Why does `command -v` exit code behave differently inside vs outside a bash function?
Consider the following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# List of required commands
required_commands=('git', 'curl', 'sdfsdf', 'jq')

# this will correctly exit if the 'git' command is missing
cc1='git'
command -v '$cc1' >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Missing '$cc1' cannot run."; exit 1; } 

# this function, when called below will have an error exit code for each
missing_commands=()
check_command() {
    command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 || missing_commands+=("$1")
}

# check each required command
for cmd in "${required_commands[@]}"; do
    check_command "$cmd"
done

# Check if any commands are missing
if [ ${#missing_commands[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "All required commands are available. Starting the script..."
    # Your script continues here
else
    echo "The following commands are required but not installed:"
    for missing_cmd in "${missing_commands[@]}"; do
        echo "  - $missing_cmd"
    done
    exit 1
fi

# continue if all commands are available
echo "All required commands are available. Starting."

Unfortunately, when called inside the check_command() function, the exit code for command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 is always non-zero?? This seems unusual, and I can't understand what the difference seems to be.
The target OS here is MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71), running in ZSH in a plain terminal.

Please paste your script at shellcheck.net and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Brilliant ... nice to know such a tool exists. And the problem:  commas as separators in the bash array .

You may want to review the shell guide by Google: https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html - there are a few issues in your script that might cause unexpected problems later ....

Thanks to @Cyrus and help from https://shellcheck.net, the answer turned out to be my own silliness... commas are not used as separators in bash arrays, so the following line:
required_commands=('git', 'curl', 'sdfsdf', 'jq')

results in four items, each ending in a , character. Oops.

Your command has additional issues including that $cc1 won't be expanded inside single quotes in command -v '$cc1'. Run it through http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag you used tells you to do - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".
